# How to make a correct Joomla URL using the Joomla Classes

Tags: php, url, joomla, joomla1.5

I am busy making a Joomla!  component. And know i want to link to another component. So, as example i want to link from my component 'my_component' to 'his_component'. Normally this is simple to do. Just make a normal link like href="?option=com_his_component". But the problem is that one of my consumers uses SEO friendly URLs. And in that case this URL won't work.

Does anyone know a way to this the correct way (I think with the Joomla! Api)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap that link with a call to [`JRoute::_($url)`](http://api.joomla.org/Joomla-Framework/JRoute.html):

```
$link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_his_component&foo=bar');
```